# Programmatically lock a column in ExtJS

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.2

I have column locking in my grid working successfully within my code with `locked: true`.  And at runtime I can lock/unlock columns manually via the grid interface.

However I want a certain column to lock when a button is pressed.  How do I lock a column dynamically/programmaticaly?  I was expecting/hoping for a "setLocked" method, but that does not seem to exist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Grid has methods **.lock(column)** and **.unlock(column)**.
For this grid with button on toolbar
[image]

button click listener is:

```
onClick: function(button) {
        var grid = button.up('grid');
        var column = grid.down('gridcolumn[text=column1]');
        if (column.locked) {
            grid.unlock(column);
        } else {
            grid.lock(column);
        }
}
```

Comment: this doesn't work for me, I get a "TypeError: Cannot read property 'headerCt' of undefined" when I try to unlock/lock